# css inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance, twitter

I've just added the Twitter script to my website, and cannot, despite inexpertly consulting firebug, determine how to alter the css to make the feed appear uniform with the other text on my page.

The page in question is 
http://willworth.co.uk/latest.htm

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance.

As I improve, I will help the community as best I can

Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a font-size of 1.3em, and a font-family of Verdana applied to your P tags, you need to apply the same formatting to the twitter div.

Comment: Bang on.  Thank you SO much.  Muddling in the dark sometimes works for me, but this time your light REALLY helped!

Answer (score 3):

You've applied your font styling etc to the `<p>` tag only.

The content of your twitter `<div>` contains no `<p>`, and doesn't descend from a `<p>`.

You need to change the markup to wrap with paragraph tags, or change the CSS to apply the font styling to the `<div>` or more likely the `<body>`

edit: heh, Jonathan actually looked at the source :) The reason this doesn't show up in firebug (and so for me too!) is because it didn't parse as Jonathan points out. FB only reports the state of the page as it exists.

Comment: Superb!  Thank you.  I will investigate this and update this page accordingly.  It's great to have a specific direction suggested.

Thanks again

Comment: Does nobody else see the massive syntax issue in the two declarations I posted? :)

Comment: @JS - couldn't see it in firebug, but it's a good spot! Nonetheless, If the OP wants the same font shared across the doc, the correct thing to do is to move the definition to the body or a similar higher order node

Answer (score 1):

You've got the following rules in stylesheets.css on line 154:

```
#twitter_div {
        font: 1/1.5 Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        font: 100%
        }n-bottom: 1.5em;
        }

#twitter_update_list {
        font: 1/1.5 Verdana, sans-serif;
        font: 100%
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        }n-bottom: 1.5em;
        }
```

You've got an extra } where you should have a ;